# How do you program the keyless entry remote for a 2012 Chevy Malibu

Tags: chevrolet, malibu, fob

I have two remotes for Chevy Malibu I need to program them so my security alarm will work can I do this myself? If so how is it done? I have a 2012.

Answer (score 2):

After consulting some online databases (google.com), special dealer equipment is needed to program the remote for a 2012 Malibu.  Some GM cars to have a manual procedure to learn remotes, but this doesn't appear to be one of them.